# Como salvo um txt em ANSI com fwrite?

Tags: php

Quando eu executo o código PHP abaixo

```
$arquivo = fopen("emails.txt","w");

while($dados = $cod_user->fetch_array()){ 
    $bla = $dados['descricao'];
    echo $dados["descricao"]."<br>";
    fwrite($arquivo,$bla);
}
```

Ele está salvando automaticamente o `.txt` na codificação UTF-8, mas quero que ele salve em ANSI.

Meu provedor Locaweb tem algo a ver?

Comment: Como você sabe que está salvando em UTF-8? A codificação vai ser definida pelo conteúdo da variavel `$bla`.

Comment: Quando abro arquivo no Notepad++, ele informa que está em UTF-8

Comment: Junior, o notepad++ não tem certeza absoluta da codificação. Se você tem certeza que está em UTF-8 pode usar a resposta do Leo, ela vai funcionar.

Comment: Na verdade quando o `fopen` cria o documento ele cria em UTF-8, até em branco o arquivo está UTF-8, quero que `fopen` cria o txt em outra codificação.

Answer (score 3):

Pode tentar isso

```
$bla = mb_convert_encoding($bla, 'UTF-8', 'codificação' );

Codificações de Caracteres Suportadas: codificação

http://www.php.com.br/index.doc.php?doc=php/mbstring.supported-encodings.html
```

Comment: Coloquei o código mas o arquivo gerado ainda é em UTF-8. Bloco de Notas ele também informa que o arquivo está em UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que ANSI na verdade você esta se referindo aos caracteres compatíveis com iso-8859-1 ou windows-1252 (ou outro próximo disto), resumindo qualquer coisa que não seja *Unicode* com acentos *latinos*, sendo este o caso você pode experimentar usar o `iconv` para converter

### Usando 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT'

O `TRANSLIT` tenta converter de UTF-8 para iso-8859-1

```
 $bla = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $dados['descricao']);
```

### Usando 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE'

O `IGNORE` irá converter todos e se houver caracteres que não puder ele irá ignorar eles:

```
 $bla = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $dados['descricao']);
```

### Diferença do IGNORE e TRANSLIT

Por exemplo o sinal `€` (euro), é "traduzido":

```
<?php
$text = "símbolo do Euro '€'.";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

Irá virar:

> ```
> Original : símbolo do Euro '€'.
> TRANSLIT : símbolo do Euro 'EUR'.
> IGNORE   : símbolo do Euro ''.
> ```

### Resolvendo na conexão

Talvez você também possa resolver na API do mysqli, basta iniciar a conexão assim:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if (!$mysqli->set_charset("latin1")) {
    printf("Error loading character set latin1: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}
```

Claro que é importante notar que isto vai afetar a sua página se você estiver também querendo exibir na página algo, todavia pode alternar entre:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}

// ... Exibe algo na página vindo do banco aqui


//muda pra latin1 pra inicia a gravar
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("latin1")) {
    printf("Error loading character set latin1: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}

$arquivo = fopen("emails.txt","w");
while($dados = $cod_user->fetch_array()){ 
    $bla = $dados['descricao'];
    fwrite($arquivo,$bla);
}
fclose($arquivo);

//Restaura para utf8
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    exit;
}
```